# How to select a range of dates in a SUMIF function in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to sum a range of values for a range of dates. C column is a date variable, F column is a number variable and E column is general. What am I doing wrong here?

```
=SUMIFS(F2:F46, E2:E46, "Food bills", C2:C51,">="& DATE(2021,11,1), C2:C51, "<="&DATE(2021,11,1))
```

Comment: Your ranges are different sizes

Answer (score 0):

The formula you provided is attempting to sum the values in column F for rows where column E contains the text "Food bills" and where the date in column C is both greater than or equal to November 1, 2021, and less than or equal to November 1, 2021. *This means it's only summing values for exactly November 1, 2021.*

If you want to sum values for the entire month of November 2021, you should adjust the second date condition to be less than or equal to November 30, 2021.

**Here's the corrected formula with the ranges matching:**

```
=SUMIFS(F2:F51, E2:E51, "Food bills", C2:C51, ">=" & DATE(2021,11,1), C2:C51, "<=" & DATE(2021,11,30))
```

Make sure that the date in column C is formatted as a date in Excel and not as text. If it's formatted as text, the comparison with the `DATE` function won't work as expected.